# Rank df by values and sum by unique variables

Tags: r

I have this df:

```
> head(orientadores)
    name    Var2 Freq rank
1  Author1    A    1    1
2  Author1    B    2    4
3  Author2    A    2    2
4  Author3    A    3    3
5  Author4    A    1    1
6  Author4    B    3    6
```

the `rank` column was calculated like this, where, if the `Var2` column is equal to `"B"`, it should store it's value doubled.

```
orientadores$rank <- orientadores$Freq * ifelse(orientadores$Var2=="B",2,1)
```

i'd like to sum the rank values by name and order them, so it would look like this:

```
> head(orientadores)
  name    final_rank
1 Author4 7
2 Author1 5
3 Author3 3
4 Author2 2
```

How to do so?
I've tried this but it wouldn't do the trick:

```
orientadores <- orientadores %>%
        group_by(Var1) %>% mutate(final_rank = sum(Freq2))
```

Comment: Use `summarise` instead of `mutate`

Comment: I would change the flow as `orientadores %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(final_rank = sum(Freq * ((Var2 == "B") + 1)))`

Comment: funyny but this is returning only one value (the total one) @akrun

Comment: Check the `group_by` step.  It is working fine for me